# How to prove that the dimension of the set of all the Polynomials up to degree n with real coefficient is $n+1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_n(R) = 1 + x + ... + x^n $
How do I prove that the dimension of $P$ is $n+1$?

Comment: Do you mean the dimension of the *vector space* of *all* polynomials of degree at most $n$?

Comment: Your question is unclear and badly phrased. Did you mean to say "Let $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of nth degree polynomials with real coefficients. Show that it has dimension n+1 over R."?

Comment: that's right, the dimensiton of the vector space of ALL polynomials of degree from 0 to n, at the most, and the coefficients are real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the vector space of $n$-th degree polynomials with real coefficients under the natural operations has dimension $n+1$, the simplest thing is to exhibit a basis.  The most natural basis is $p_0(x)=1$, $p_1(x)=x$, $p_2(x)=x^2$, ..., $p_{n}(x)=x^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was new to this group and took some time to get used to the system. Thanks a lot !